# big margin top in html email on mail and other clients

Tags: html, css, html-email, email-client

my friend developer has some problem with an html email. The big problem I can see on my mail app is a big margin-top he didn't put in the css and two little margins (right and left) with the html margin: 0;

Do you have something to suggest?

Thank you very much.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html,body{margin:0;padding:0; background-color:#f6f6f6}
table { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
span{font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height:1.7em;}
</style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"    bgcolor="#f6f6f6">
<tr height="95px" valign="middle" >
    <td width="100%" align="left" style="padding:15px"><img src="logo_email.png" width="154" height="46" alt="good" /></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#eeeeee" height="95px" valign="middle">
    <td width="100%" colspan="2" style="padding:15px"><span style="font-size:18px;color:#414042">Thank you for subscribe our newsletter.</span><br /><span style="font-size:13px;color:#414042">The Team</span></td>
</tr>
<tr height="auto" valign="top">
    <td width="100%" colspan="2" style="padding:15px"><span style="font-size:10px;color:#6d6e71">You are receiving Activity Notifications emails.</span></td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My name is Nostradamus and I can predict that your friend has this problem because he missed a margin or padding on some element.  What this element is I have no idea as you have provided me with no code.  My suggestion is to please review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  For details on how to pose a question that can actually be answered properly.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to post the code! Now It's done..

Answer (score 0):

The layout looks fine. There is an image on top that has a relative link and may not be showing - could this be the "margin-top" you are referring to?